# Kiel oni nomu sian estron en la laborejo?

Tags: word-choice

Ni imagu, ke mi estas en mia laborejo. Kiel mi nomu mian (rektan) estron, se mi volus diri al li aŭ ŝi ion sen uzi la nomon? Kiel mi komencas la parolon? Ĉu ĉi tiuj variantoj taŭgas:

> ***Estro***, mi volas diri al vi…
>
> ***Ĉefo***, ĉu vi povas…
>
> ***???***, mi…

Kiu estas la plej ĝusta vorto? En kia situacio?

Answer (score 5):

***Ĉefo,*** en mia lingvouzo, tradukas la anglan *boss* (kaj la italan *capo*), kaj mi uzus ĝin en amikeca, neformala, moketa situacio.

***Estro,*** kiel alparolo, estas por mi certagrade pli formala. Mi uzus ĝin en serioza situacio, alterne kun la specifa titolo (ekz-e *direktoro*), kiam en la itala mi uzus respektan pronomon. Tio validas por la sendependa vorto, ne por la sufikso: *Hej, bandestro!*  ne estas tre formala...

***Moŝto,*** kiu devus esti la plej formala, estas en mia sperto nuntempe uzata nur moke.

Mi nun ne povas dokumenti, kiomgrade mia uzo kongruas kun la plejmulto de la Esperantlingvaj oficejoj... Roterdamanoj, kie vi estas?

Answer (score 0):

Estro aŭ estrino. Dependas de la rilato, kiun oni havas kun la estro aŭ estrino.